# UITextField not updating

Tags: ios

I'm having trouble updating the UITextField for an iPhone app. I've set the layout with the Interface Builder, created an instance of the text field in the ViewController, and set the ViewController as the delegate for the text field.

The text field object in code doesn't seem to be responding when I enter in information and press Done.

Does anyone have any ideas why its not working?

Comment: What specifically is not working? Entering text, or pressing done?

Comment: Can you show some code and what action you want to be executed when clicking the "Done" button?

Comment: Its the pressing done part that isnt working.

Comment: self.myText = [[UITextField alloc] init];
 [self.myText becomeFirstResponder];
 self.myText.delegate = self;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating the text field in interface builder, you don't need to also alloc and init it in code. Link the text field to files owner in IB (I'm assuming files owner is your view controller) as the delegate. If you need to refer to it specifically, also create and outlet in your view controller and link that to your text field. This is covered in the most basic tutorial apps in the docs.

To respond when the done button is pressed, implement the `textFieldShouldReturn` method from the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol. Resign first responder in that method and return YES.

Answer (score 0):

Is your text field connected to the IBOutlet in your code? Maybe if you post some related code it would be helpful.